# Generate all permutations with separate limits for each index

Tags: python, list, generator, permutation

Let's say we have a list, e.g.,  `[3, 2, 1]`. I would like to generate all permutations of that list in the form:

```
[1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1] , [3, 2, 1]
```

for any list of length `n`. This way, the value of the `i`th element of the original list is the upper limit for the value of the `i`th element of all the permutations.

I would also like to use a generator using `yield`, since the input list may be rather large large (e.g., `n = 30`).

So far, I have been using something like this:

```
itertools.product(range(1, 5), repeat=5)
```

Which has the following output when used in a `for` loop:

```
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 4), (1, 1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 2, 3), ...
```

However, I don't think it allows specifying custom limits for each element of the permutations.

Also, please note that the elements of the input list do not necessarily need to be consecutive numbers, so `[25, 17, 10, 4]` is a valid input.

Comment: Why isn't `[3,3,3]` a possibility?

Comment: @RafaelC Since the second element is 2, the second element of all the permutations must be less than or equal to 2. I've edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: Does the order matters? Is `[(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1)]` a valid solution?

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo The order of the output in the question would be preferable, since they are the exponents used somewhere else and I would like the largest values to appear on the left of the list first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This recursive function returns a generator in the desired order:

```
def f(limits):
    if not limits:
        yield ()
        return

    for l in f(limits[1:]):
        for i in range(1, limits[0]+1):
            yield (i,) + l
```

---

```
>>> print(list(f([3, 2, 1])))
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1), (3, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (2, 2, 1), (3, 2, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the results of `itertools.product`

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> l = [3,2,1]
>>> list(filter(lambda t: all(x<=y for x,y in zip(t,l)), product(l, repeat=len(l))))
[(3, 2, 1), (3, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: Could you state what `l` is in the example?

Comment: @aL_eX Sorry.. Updated

Comment: This is really inefficient, it generates a LOT of tuples that are just discarded

Comment: Also, I think `repeat=3` should be replaced with `repeat=len(l)` for the general case.

Comment: @aL_eX. Thanks. Updated

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the Cartesian product of a bunch of ranges the argument of which is defined by your input list:

```
from itertools import product
lims = [3, 2, 1]
gen = product(*(range(1,lim+1) for lim in lims))
print(list(gen))
```

The result is

```
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1)]
```